# What are some good counter-arguments to the Third Man Argument

Tags: plato, parmenides

So long story short, I have to help a friend with short philosophy paper that is already overdue. I can write ideas and express them well, but I am seriously lost with this topic and I'm a bit short on time. So, to keep it brief, what is a good counter argument to the Third Man argument and support for Plato's original theory of forms.
TL;DR: Counter the Third Man argument.
Thanks in advance.
Edit: I apologize for breaking regulations by asking such a question. It was my first time posting.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. We do not do HW for people, we would answer HW related questions if a thinking process is presented in the post, and some specific difficulty identified.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first time posting and I apologize for breaking regulations. I will keep that in mind when using the website in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See at least :

- Gregory Vlastos, [The Third Man Argument in the Parmenides](http://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/VlastosTMA.pdf) (1954)
- P.T. Geach, [The Third Man Again](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2182189?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (1956)
- S.Marc Cohen, [The Logic of the Third Man](https://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/CohenTMA.pdf) (1971).